# Consulta a dos bases de datos diferentes Mysql con mysqli_query php

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Tengo dos bases de datos Mysql declaradas en PHP así:

```
$conexion1 = new mysqli($servidor1,$usuario1,$pass1,$nombreBd1);
$conexion2 = new mysqli($servidor2,$usuario2,$pass2,$nombreBd2);
```

Y esta es mi consulta:

```
        $res= $conexion1 and conexion2->query("select *, negocio.negocio, negocio.codigo from 
        contacto
        inner join negocio
        on contacto.codigo = negocio.codigo
        where (contacto.barrio ='$ubicacionN')order by negocio ")or die($conexion1 and 
        conexion2->error);  
        while($f=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
        echo '<option value="'.$f[12].'">'.$f[17].'</option>';  
        }
```

Obviamente esta no es la forma adecuada o correcta de realizar la consulta, pero es lo que necesitaría.

¿Cómo se aplica correctamente este método?

Comment: Las conexiones entre las bases de datos, son internas entre ellas... Si ese query funciona en una de las dos, te alcanza con correrlo contra esa...

Comment: @gbianchi No funciona, por que si bien las bases de datos están alojadas en el mismo servidor, tienen acceso independiente.

Comment: Si no me equivoco para que pudiera funcionar una sentencia entre dos bases de datos diferentes, debería de existir un enlace entre las dos **DB LINK** que seria el puente a una BD remota.

Comment: @Arjona entonces tu pregunta es como conectar dos bases de datos.. no en php, si no en mysql....

Comment: Tú puedes hacerlo **desde una sola conexión** a condición de que el usuario con el que conectas tenga acceso a ambas bases de datos. Poniendo antes de la tabla el nombre de la base de datos, como de hecho lo tienes, no debería haber ningún problema.