# Sumar valores de mysqli_fetch_row

Tags: php, mysql, array

Tengo la siguiente consulta

```
$resp = $conexionAd->query("select negocio.codigo from negocio where plantilla = 'plantilla1'")or die($conexionAd -> error);
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resp)){
    $re7 = $conexionCa->query("select count(id) from productos where codigo = '".$fila[0]."' group by codigo")or die($conexionCa -> error);
    while($fila7 = mysqli_fetch_row($re7)){
        print_r($fila7);
    }
} 
print_r($fila7);


Array ( [0] => 4 ) 
Array ( [0] => 23 )

$value7 = 23
```

Necesito sumar valores de clave [0] para obtener $value7 = 27

Comment: No entiendo por qué ejecutas una consulta dentro de un bucle que lee resultados de otra consulta. Es una pésima idea. ¿Puedes explicar qué es lo que debe hacer tu código? Las dos tablas se pueden relacionar con un `JOIN` y hacer una sola consulta.

Comment: A. Cedano Lo hago así por que cada consulta pertenece a una base de datos diferente

Comment: La pregunta es: ¿por qué están en BD distintas si, por lo que se ve en el código son tablas que guardan una relación? No obstante, puedes hacer `JOIN` en tablas en BD distintas, a condición de que el mismo usuario tenga privilegios de acceso a ambas BD. Este código es pésimo desde todos los puntos de vista: dos conexiones, dos base de datos, una consulta a otra BD dentro de la lectura de datos de otra consulta a otra BD. ¿Por qué no están en la misma BD? ¿Qué justifica que estén separadas?

Comment: De echo así lo intente, pero no permite https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/555616/consulta-a-dos-bases-de-datos-diferentes-mysql-con-mysqli-query-php En todo caso la consulta actual es de otro tema. Agradezco tu colaboración.

Comment: En esa pregunta te hice un comentario, y no me dijiste si el usuario tendría acceso a ambas bases de datos ¿? Otra cosa, los array que se ven en la pregunta son del `while` interno es uno de cada uno? Tú puedes sumar los datos en la consulta SQL con `SUM` por ejemplo.

Comment: El array es del while $fila7, la segunda consulta. La primer consulta me arroja dos códigos, luego la segunda consulta busca estos dos códigos y arroja el conteo por cada uno. (codigo1 = Array ( [0] => 4 ) ) , (codigo2 = Array ( [0] => 23 ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tú puedes crear una variable inicializada a `0` y luego irle agregando los valores, por ejemplo:

```
$suma=0;
$resp = $conexionAd->query("select negocio.codigo from negocio where plantilla = 'plantilla1'") or die($conexionAd -> error);
while($fila = $resp->fetch_row()){
    $re7 = $conexionCa->query("select count(id) from productos where codigo = '$fila[0]' group by codigo") or die($conexionCa -> error);
    while($fila7 = $re7->fetch_row()){
        $suma+=$fila7[0];
    }
} 

echo $suma;
```

De todos modos, deberías pensar seriamente en optimizar y si fuera posible, en tener todo en la misma base de datos.

Por otra parte, evita la mezcla de estilos. He cambiado el código al estilo orientado a objetos, que ya usabas al llamar a `query()`.

Comment: Funciono perfectamente. Acatare tus observaciones. Muchas Gracias....